# JavaScript: Set PHP session inside a JavaScript and the variable of session is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, session

Is there a way to set a PHP session inside a JavaScript and the variable of the session is from a JavaScript variable.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function save_chart(chart, filename) {

var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        download(data, filename + '.png');
}
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['image'] = "<script>document.write(data)</script>"?>, 
    window.open("/cert/forms/contents/reports/incidents/chart-img.php", "", "width=800,height=800")

</script>
```

I want that the var data will be set as a PHP SESSION. Is there any way to do this?

Or any other way but only to get variable to another page by using `$_POST['image']` or `$_SESSION['image']` in PHP.

Comment: i think it is not possible to use php inside javascript

Comment: @mtizziani actually it's possible, coz i have `while statement` inside a highcharts

Comment: Since PHP runs on the server, you need to make a new request to send that data. If you want to do it without actually submitting a form and reloading the page, then your keyword is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

PHP session data is saved on the server-side. Hence it's impossible to access them directly from JavaScript. However, if you can either:

1. Create a server-side API that will receive the data through an AJAX request sent via JavaScript and save it to a session variable. Or
2. If you just want to save persistent data on the client-side, You can use any of the available client-side storage API in JavaScript.

**Client-side storage API**

- [The Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache): That's not the normal HTTP caching. The Cache API is a JavaScript interface that allows developers to programmatically store files on the client-side with more advanced functionalities than what the HTTP cache headers can provide.
- The [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) APIs which provides an easy way to save data in the form of key-value pairs. (However, it should not be used to store large files. Read the documentation to see more about its limitations)
- [The indexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) Which is currently the most advanced way to store and handle huge amounts of data on the client-side and allows you to perform high-performance index-based queries on that data.